# Thumbsup: Why is $user_id interpreted as a function?

Tags: php, function, callback, warnings

**Details**

User with `id=12` tries to open a page, the following error occurs:

**Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function `'12'` not found or invalid function name in E:\thumbsup2\classes\thumbsup.php on line 201**

The offending line is `$user_id = (int) call_user_func(ThumbsUp::config('user_id_callback'));`

thumbsup.php

```
public static function get_user_id()
{
    // Cache
    static $user_id = FALSE;

    // This code only needs to be executed once per request
    if ($user_id !== FALSE)
        return $user_id;

    // The callback config is left empty
    if ( ! ThumbsUp::config('user_id_callback'))
        return $user_id = NULL;

    // Load the user id
    $user_id = (int) call_user_func(ThumbsUp::config('user_id_callback'));//<<-- line 201

    // Set user id to NULL if not found
    return ($user_id) ? $user_id : $user_id = NULL;
}
```

in config.php

```
 'user_id_callback' => $userz_id, //                                 <<-- $userz_id is 12
```

**QUESTIONS**

How can I return 12 as the $user_id ? Why is 12 being interpreted as a function?

Comment: Does the class, or any of it's parents, have a __call or __get function?

Comment: surely the problem is that you're using call_user_func() and passing it a user_id from your config rather than a callable function?

Comment: How do I go about making it a callable function? Or is there another way to pass the user_id's value to thumbsup.php Sorry if this sounds like a daft question.

Comment: I believe I may have found the solution 
  `$user_id = ThumbsUp::config('user_id_callback');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need the call_user_func method at all. it looks like all you're doing is loading your user id from the config file, it doesnt look like youre doing anything to modify it so that should work.

```
$user_id = ThumbsUp::config('user_id_callback');
```

Answer (score 1):

Because
        call_user_func(::config('user_id_callback'))
and user_id_callback is 12.